# Conditionally formatting entire column in excel based on text value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have data including columns upto DI and rows increasing everyday.Row 4 has the header for each column. I want to highlight every column which has word "avg" in it. I have tried using the formula = A$4="avg"(for current sheet i also tried=$AI$4="avg"). But it doesn't yield any result nor =$A$4="avg". How should i proceed. On every YouTube video i have found they have used somehow A$4 to fix the reference row for conditional formatting to look for reference cell but it doesn't work for me. It doesn't even highlight single cell.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below CF rule.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("avg",A$4:Z$4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks the above formula works. Can you explain why just "avg" did not worked